# Windows 7 crashes when connects to internet

Tags: windows-7, internet, wireless-networking

I've just started to encounter a problem with Win7.

My PC is fine until I connect to the net using wireless. I use a dongle and can connect it to the PC without issue and everything works correctly.

However when I connect to the internet my pc freezes and thats it I need to forcefully restart.

I've tried closing programs in the taskmanager so I'm left with the bare essentials but something is killing it.

Is there anyway to determine what is causing the problems?

Comment: Wrong place to ask this question. Only programming related questions here.

Answer (score 0):

99% sure its the drivers for the wireless card.  Try the card in another computer if you can, and see if it responds the same way.  It sounds like the drivers are locking up the system pretty badly.